# Question about who uses and when or how to use a design pattern was closed

Tags: discussion, support, reopen-closed, opinion-based

I've asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395268/when-to-use-the-builder-pattern-in-real-projects) a few minutes ago and unfortunately 5 users voted it to be closed without giving me any hint in the comment why they did so.

Unfortunately, I don't really understand why they voted for closing since my 3 questions were not answered.
I understand that the first question is opinion-based. But the other 2 are definitely not and I'd love to get an answer to these.

What is your opinion on this closure?

How could I improve the question so that it wouldn't have gotten closed or gets reopened?

Comment: @deceze: actually it didn't since like I mentioned that 2 of the 3 questions asked are not about opinions...

Comment: Only the last of the three questions seems rather un-opinionated. "When should typically..." is *rather broad* and a close reason in itself. How about you rephrase the question to focus exclusively on the last concrete question?

Comment: If you insist on asking three questions in one, you have three possibilities for your question to be down or close-voted.

Comment: Interesting. I understand that the first two questions could be interpreted as opinion-questions and that many people didn't even read onto the 3rd one. What I don't get though is that a question from someone else which is way more opinion based and **very broad** gets upvoted to heaven (i just found this thread while looking for an answer to my 3rd question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern?rq=1 how would you explain this?

Comment: That question is from *seven years ago*. I doubt it would be as well-accepted now. The rules have been refined over time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question was closed, officially, as Primarily Opinion based. You ask three distinct questions. Generally, this means the question is too broad.

Your questions:

> - Is it something you often use?

This type of question isn't revelant, is it? Do you really care if someone uses this often? What do you, or future readers, get out of an answer that says "Yes, I use this all the time" or "Nope, I dislike using this".

This question is really a set up for your second question...

> - What are typical situations when you'd use it?

This is too broad or opinion based. "Typical situations" depends on a lot of circumstances. What I consider typical in my line of work is very different from what others in another line of work consider typical. There are too many possible answers to this sub-question.

> - How can I add a syntax to a builder so that I can only call .WithXYZ on a certain object? (see the bottom of the page for more detail)

Here is your real question. Unfortunately, you've buried it under two off-topic questions. It didn't stand much of a chance.

---

Focus your question. Make it specific to what you want to fix/do. The questions about typical situations or whether this is utilized often aren't relevant. They are also broad and opinion-generating questions. Both of these are close reasons.

Comment: +1 for the OP for asking, and +5 for you explaining the OP how this question can be salvaged and get turned into a good one. (Yes: I clicked the Up button 5 times. But that lead to a stalemate so I pressed it again.)

Comment: @Andy: Thank you for this insightful and detailed answer! The information I wished from the question "_Is it something you often use?_" was not "_Yes/No, I use it all the time / dislike using it_" but rather "_Yes/No, I use it all the time / dislike using it, [BECAUSE...]_" so to get to learn from the experiences of others. I do see, that the typical situations are too broad and difficult to answer. I will try to focus on the most important questions next time. Thanks again :-)